# How to rotate a figure without moving around the stage(actionscript)

Tags: flash, actionscript

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    public class Bullet extends MovieClip {
        private var mc:MovieClip;
        public function Bullet() {

            mc = new MovieClip();
            mc.graphics.beginFill(0);
            mc.graphics.drawRect(120, 120, 40, 40);
            mc.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(mc);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }

        private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void{

            mc.rotation += 10;

        }

    }

}
```

how can i make the rotation of the circle without moving him around the stage, just staying in the place he was before and just rotate, not moving anywhere is that posible??

if you try this code you'll see that the circle is rotating and moving around the stage, so that i don't want, how can i change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By rotating around a registration point in the center of the objects you wish to rotate.

[Yahoo Astra](http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/astra-flash/) has a [Dynamic Registration](http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/astra-flash/classreference/com/yahoo/astra/utils/DynamicRegistration.html) class for things like this.

This could be implemented as:

```
package
{
    import com.yahoo.astra.utils.DynamicRegistration;

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class Bullet extends MovieClip
    {
        private var mc:MovieClip;
        private var currentRotation:uint = 0;

        public function Bullet()
        {
            mc = new MovieClip();
            mc.graphics.beginFill(0);
            mc.graphics.drawRect(120, 120, 40, 40);
            mc.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(mc);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }

        private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
        {
            currentRotation = (currentRotation + 10) % 360;
            DynamicRegistration.rotate(mc, new Point(140, 140), currentRotation);
        }

    }
}
```

Yahoo Astra DynamicRegistration class:

```
/*
Copyright (c) 2008 Yahoo! Inc.  All rights reserved.  
The copyrights embodied in the content of this file are licensed under the BSD (revised) open source license
*/
package com.yahoo.astra.utils
{
        import flash.geom.Point;
        import flash.display.DisplayObject;

        /**
         * Allows you to manipulate display objects based on a registration point other
         * than the standard (0,0).
         * 
         * @author Josh Tynjala
         */
        public class DynamicRegistration
        {
                /**
                 * Moves a <code>DisplayObject</code> to a new position (x,y) based on a registration point. The
                 * true position of the object will be (x - registration.x, y - registration.y).
                 * 
                 * @param       target                          the DisplayObject to move
                 * @param       registration            the registration point of the DisplayObject
                 * @param       x                                       the new x position, in pixels
                 * @param       y                                       the new y position, in pixels
                 */
                public static function move(target:DisplayObject, registration:Point, x:Number = 0, y:Number = 0):void
                {
                        //generate the location of the registration point in the parent
                        registration = target.localToGlobal(registration);
                        registration = target.parent.globalToLocal(registration);

                        //move the target and offset by the registration point
                        target.x += x - registration.x;
                        target.y += y - registration.y;
                }

                /**
                 * Rotates a <code>DisplayObject</code> based on a registration point. 
                 * 
                 * @param       target                          the DisplayObject to move
                 * @param       registration            the registration point of the DisplayObject
                 * @param       rotation                        the new rotation angle
                 */
                public static function rotate(target:DisplayObject, registration:Point, degrees:Number = 0):void
                {
                        changePropertyOnRegistrationPoint(target, registration, "rotation", degrees);
                }

                /**
                 * Scales a <code>DisplayObject</code> based on a registration point. 
                 * 
                 * @param       target                          the DisplayObject to move
                 * @param       registration            the registration point of the DisplayObject
                 * @param       scaleX                          the new x scaling factor
                 * @param       scaleY                          the new y scaling factor
                 */
                public static function scale(target:DisplayObject, registration:Point, scaleX:Number = 0, scaleY:Number = 0):void
                {
                        changePropertyOnRegistrationPoint(target, registration, "scaleX", scaleX);
                        changePropertyOnRegistrationPoint(target, registration, "scaleY", scaleY);
                }

                /**
                 * @private
                 * Alters an arbitary property based on the registration point.
                 * 
                 * @param       target                          the DisplayObject to move
                 * @param       registration            the registration point of the DisplayObject
                 * @param       propertyName            the property to change
                 * @param       value                           the new value of the property to change
                 */
                private static function changePropertyOnRegistrationPoint(target:DisplayObject, registration:Point, propertyName:String, value:Number):void
                {
                        //generate the location of the registration point in the parent
                        var a:Point = registration.clone();
                        a = target.localToGlobal(a);
                        a = target.parent.globalToLocal(a);

                        target[propertyName] = value;

                        //after the property change, regenerate the location of the registration
                        //point in the parent
                        var b:Point = registration.clone();
                        b = target.localToGlobal(b);
                        b = target.parent.globalToLocal(b);

                        //move the target based on the difference to make it appear the change
                        //happened based on the registration point
                        target.x -= b.x - a.x;
                        target.y -= b.y - a.y;
                }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Registration Point (or the point about which the object rotates) is set to `(0, 0)` i.e. the top-left corner of that DisplayObject.

When you do

```
mc.graphics.drawRect(120, 120, 40, 40);
```

The rectangle is drawn with its top-left corner at co-ordinates `(120, 120)` and its center will be at `(140, 140)`

You can simply draw the rectangle such that its center will be at `(0, 0)` and move this movieclip in its parent (so that the net result is the same)

```
mc.graphics.drawRect(-20, -20, 40, 40);
mc.x=140;
mc.y=140;
```

Then, `mc.rotation+=10` will rotate the rectangle about its center.